# Why do I have to declare an array for ping tool

Tags: php

I couldn't understand why I have to declare an array `$output` for my php code.
I could use `$status` instead for returning value 0 or 1.

```
<?php
   exec ("ping -c 3  $ip",$output, $status );
   if ($status == 0)
   {
     echo "host is up";
   }
   else
   {
     echo "host is down";
   }
?>
```

Comment: That is how the function works. There is nothing more to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass the third argument, you have to pass the second argument as well, so you have to put something there. If you're not interested in the output, do what the documentation says:

> If you do not want the function to append elements, call unset() on
>   the array before passing it to exec().

However, I just tried this myself, it doesn't work. It always fills in the variable with the output.  So if you're not interested in the output, use shell syntax to redirect it:

```
exec ("ping -c 3  $ip >/dev/null 2>&1",$output, $status );
```

Comment: please give me example of calling unset() on the array

Comment: hi, im not ably to login getting error Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more. <?php
echo "enter your username\n";
$username = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "your name\n";
$name =  trim(fgets(STDIN));
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","sqldata","sqldata","accounts");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$query= "DELETE FROM uptable WHERE name='$name'";
$result= mysql_query($query);
if ($result)
{
echo "done";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: my code not working getting error all the time when trying to delete user from database

Comment: If they don't want you asking questions here, why do you think you can get around it by posting your questions in a comment? Anyway, you're mixing mysqli and mysql functions, you can't do that.

Comment: Maybe stupid questions like this are the reason you're banned. You need to use mysqli_query instead of mysql_query. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: no didn't work, you my first posting, i didnt post anywhere... i change all mysql to mysqli this error msg im getting PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant mysqli_query - assumed 'mysqli_query' in /root/phptest/delete1.php on line 23

Comment: That error comes when you forget to put `$` before a variable name. You must be missing the `()` after `mysqli_query` somewhere, so it thinks it's variable instead of a function. Your comments have nothing to do with this question, please stop posting here.